# Minimum of general quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asking to find the minimum value of the following quadratic form
$$
\left|\left|x-Mz\right|\right|_2^2=\langle x-Mz,x-Mz\rangle=z^TM^TMz-2(M^Tx)z+x^Tx
$$

where $x$ is a constant vector, $M$ is constant $p\times k$ matrix with full rank where $p>k$. I need to find $z$ such that the above reaches its minimum.

Noticing for classic quadratic function $ax^2+bx+c$ the minimum is reached when $x=-\frac{b}{2a}$, so I guess
$$
z="-\frac{-2(M^Tx)}{2M^TM}"=(M^TM)^{-1}M^Tx
$$

is what we want. And after boring calculation, it turns out it is.

My question is, is there any intuitive way to show the result? Or any simple proof?

Answer (score 1):

You do it the same way you would do for the classic scalar quadratic function $f(z)=az^2+bz+c$: calculate de derivative $f'(z)$, set it equal to zero and solve for $z$, with the difference that with the "vector" quadratic form we use matrix differentiation.

Thus, for the quadratic form

$$f(x)=z^TAz+b^Tz+c$$

with $z \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (symmetric PSD), $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$\frac{df(z)}{dz} = 2z^TA+b^T=0 \Rightarrow z=-\frac{1}{2}A^{-1}b.$$

In your case, for $A=M^TM$ and $b=-2M^Tx$, we get $$z=(M^TM)^{-1}M^Tx.$$

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of it as the following problem. You want to approximate the vector $x$ (in a least squares sense) by a linear combination of the columns of the matrix $M$. So your solution is in the column space of $M$. If you think of it geometrically, the solution is the projection of $x$ on the space spanned by the columns of $M$. Consequently, the error $Mz-x$ must be orthogonal to the column space of $M$ (if it were not, then you could decrease the length of the error vector by choosing $z$ such that the error becomes orthogonal). The orthogonality requirement is

$$M^T(Mz-x)=0$$

from which directly follows

$$z=(M^TM)^{-1}M^Tx$$

if the inverse exists.